# Dataframe column that combines two columns and counts how many times each value appears

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the following structure:

```
key ticket_id             ticket_category
    
CNI-1    T1               Reset
CNI-2    T2, T3           Reset, Error
CNI-3    T1, T4           Reset, Server
CNI-4    T4, T5, T6, T7   Server, Server, Server, Error
CNI-5    T1, T8, T9, T10  Reset, Reset, Error, Server
```

Is it possible to create a new column that will count how many times each category appears in a row and the matching ticket(s)?

Desired output:

```
key      ticket_id        ticket_category                 combined
    
CNI-1    T1               Reset                           Reset - 1(T1)
CNI-2    T2, T3           Reset, Error                    Reset - 1(T1), Error - 1(T2)
CNI-3    T1, T4           Reset, Server                   Reset - 1(T1), Server - 1(T4)
CNI-4    T4, T5, T6, T7   Server, Server, Server, Error   Server - 3(T4, T5, T6), Error - 1(T7)
CNI-5    T1, T8, T9, T10  Reset, Reset, Error, Server     Reset - 2(T1, T8), Error - 1(T9), Server - 1(T10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple `groupby` to construct the dataframe you need. See the comments in the code for the explanation:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"key": [f"CNI-{i+1}" for i in range(5)],
                   "ticket_id": ["T1", "T2, T3", "T1, T4", "T4, T5, T6, T7", "T1, T8, T9, T10"],
                   "ticket_category": ["Reset", "Reset, Error", "Reset, Server", "Server, Server, Server, Error", "Reset, Reset, Error, Server"]
                   })

#convert strings to lists for explode
df = data.copy().set_index("key").apply(lambda x: x.str.split(", "))

#explode to get one row per ticket_id
df = df.explode(column=list(df.columns)).reset_index()

#get count of ticket_category per original row
df["count"] = df.groupby(["key","ticket_category"])["ticket_id"].transform("count")

#groupby and construct labels
df = df.groupby(["key", "ticket_category"], as_index=False, sort=False).agg({"count": "first", "ticket_id": ", ".join})
df["combined"] = df["ticket_category"] + " - " + df["count"].astype(str) + "(" + df["ticket_id"] + ")"

#get back original df structure
df = df.groupby("key")["ticket_category", "ticket_id", "combined"].agg(", ".join).reset_index()

#get back the original column from the original data
df["ticket_category"] = df["key"].map(dict(zip(data["key"],data["ticket_category"])))

>>> df
     key                ticket_category        ticket_id  \
0  CNI-1                          Reset               T1   
1  CNI-2                   Reset, Error           T2, T3   
2  CNI-3                  Reset, Server           T1, T4   
3  CNI-4  Server, Server, Server, Error   T4, T5, T6, T7   
4  CNI-5    Reset, Reset, Error, Server  T1, T8, T9, T10   

                                            combined  
0                                      Reset - 1(T1)  
1                       Reset - 1(T2), Error - 1(T3)  
2                      Reset - 1(T1), Server - 1(T4)  
3              Server - 3(T4, T5, T6), Error - 1(T7)  
4  Reset - 2(T1, T8), Error - 1(T9), Server - 1(T10)
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. In the meantime, I received more data. I updated the question. Your solution is not working as expected and I think it's because the ticket_id can be found for different keys. I'm currently trying to adapt your solution but any help is much apreciated.

Comment: @rzss275 - Please be fair and post a new post for a new question going forward. Your original question was answered as requested. And my code works fine with a few small changes for your updated data as well. See the edit.